# What is difference between Crypt... and CP... functions?

Tags: winapi, cryptoapi

I try to learn WIN API. I found [base cryptographic functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380252%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#base_cryptography_functions) such as [CryptEcrypt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379924%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [CSP Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380252%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#csp_functions) such as `CPEncrypt`. Also I read [this](http://www.progtown.com/topic175686-differences.html). I would like to clarify. If I use CPEncrypt then I call CSP functions directly, without CriptoAPI? And if I use CryptEcrypt, it calls CriptoAPI, and CriptoAPI calls CSP functions?
What is difference between Crypt... and CP... functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is difference between Crypt... and CP... functions?

The *CP* functions are the underlying implementations of the `CryptoAPI` within a particular CSP.

> If I use CPEncrypt then I call CSP functions directly, without
>   CriptoAPI?

Do not call them directly; abusing the intended use pattern of a security API is a very bad idea and in the case of the CryptoAPI the intended pattern is to go via the API's `CryptXXX` functions.

> And if I use CryptEcrypt, it calls CriptoAPI, and CriptoAPI calls CSP functions?

`CryptEncrypt` is part of the CryptoAPI, calling it will eventually invoke `CPEncrypt` in whatever CSP you are using.